# Manually set a proxy as dead using scrapy-rotating-proxies package

Tags: proxy, scrapy, package, proxies

I am using a proxy rotation in my project to prevent being banned from a website, I have to scrape a list of urls http://website/0001 to http://website/9999 and when it's detect that I am scraping they send me to the website/contact.html.

I already have my proxy list in the settings 
`ROTATING_PROXY_LIST = [
    'proxy1.com:8000',
    'proxy2.com:8031',
    # ...
]`

And I created this Spider:

```
    next_page_url = response.url[17:]//getting the relative url from website/page

    if next_page_url == "contact.html":

        absolute_next_page = response.urljoin(last_page)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page)
        //should try the same page with different proxy
    else:
        next_page_url = int(next_page_url)+1
        last_page = str(next_page_url).zfill(4)
        absolute_next_page = response.urljoin(last_page)
        yield Request(absolute_next_page)`
```

But it gives an error saying UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last_page' referenced before assignment

How can I specify that the proxy is dead in this spider? Or is there another way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to ask?

You are saying you got error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'last_page' referenced before assignment
```

This error states that you are trying to use a variable that is not currency initialized.

So to prevent this error, change your code like this

```
next_page_url = response.url[17:]//getting the relative url from website/page

next_page_url = int(next_page_url)+1
last_page = str(next_page_url).zfill(4)
absolute_next_page = response.urljoin(last_page)

if next_page_url == "contact.html":

        next_page_url = int(next_page_url)+1
        absolute_next_page = response.urljoin(last_page)

        req = Request(url = absolute_next_page)

        // If you want to try the same link again, then do this
        // req = Request(url = response.url)

        req.meta['proxy'] = random.choice(ROTATING_PROXY_LIST) // choose a random proxy

        yield req

else:

        yield Request(absolute_next_page)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I've initialized the last_page as a global variable after the start_urls variable, because if it enter in contact.html, it have to return to the same link that I was trying to access in the last request, I still don't know how to do that.

Comment: Hmm, thats a class variable, not local variable. if you want to access class variable from within a function, do `self.last_page`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! but now it's says NameError: name 'random' is not defined, I thought random was already defined, should I create this?

Comment: Hehehe you look newbie to Python, add `import random` at the top of file